# Java detect pendrive in Ubuntu with file.listFiles()

Tags: java, ubuntu, usb-drive

I am using a Thread in order to check peridodically whether a pendrive is coneccted or not, changing between two states EMPTY / READY

```
@Override
public void run() {
    running = true;
    while(running){ // forever
        try {
            Delay.of_1second();
            drivePath = getDrivePath(rootPath);
            if (isReady() && drivePath==null){
                notifyNewState(DriveState.EMPTY);
            }
            else if (!isReady() && drivePath!=null){
                notifyNewState(DriveState.READY);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private String getDrivePath(String rootPath){
    File file = new File(rootPath);
    if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS){
        return file.exists() ? rootPath : null;
    }
    else{
        for (File f : file.listFiles()){
            if (!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("CDROM")){
                return f.getAbsolutePath(); // we return the first folder other than 'CDROM'
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It works pretty well in Windows with rootPath="E:\", but is does not work in Ubuntu rootPath="/media/ubuntu", the strange point that I still dont understand is that **the Thread works fine if I open the pendrive in the file manager**, but I need it working as soon as the pendrive is plugged-in the usb port, not when the user browses the files with the file manager. What could I do ?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux machines there are two commands I can think of which give you useful information about which devices are plugged in. The first is `lsusb`. When I run it on my machine:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 021: ID 0718:061a Imation Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
...
```

The second line is my pen drive. 
Another command is dmesg

```
[148541.700254] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[148830.993250] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 21
[148836.316642] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 22 using ehci-pci
[148836.415145] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=..., idProduct=....
[148836.415157] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[148836.415162] usb 2-1.2: Product: iPhone
[148836.415167] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
[148836.415171] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: ....
[148836.894819] ipheth 2-1.2:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet device attached
```

You can set your program to poll either of these commands and parse the output i.e. using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dmesg)"`.

I would consider this solution a work-around and I imagine there is a wealth of other possible methods of detecting when a USB drive is connected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but once I know the pen is plugged-in (with your suggestion) how do I access it using File file = new File("path-to-pen"); This is not working till I browse the pendrive with the file manager